# How to set an ortographic camera to project like described?

Tags: orthographic, projection-matrix

I would like the projection to be like this:

[image: three-axis projection]

That is, `(x,y,z) -> (x-y/sqrt(2),y/sqrt(2)-z)`

How to find the projection matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this by using a simple camera:

```
var camera = new THREE.Camera();
```

Setting it's far and near views to big values:

```
camera.far=2000;
camera.near=-2000;
```

And setting a projection matrix like this:

```
camera.projectionMatrix = camera.projectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4(
            1,0,0.5,0,
            0,-1,-0.5,0,
            0,1,0,0,
            0,0,0,2000);
```

I'm not sure 0.5 is the right value (guess it should be 1/sqrt(2)) but it worked. Also, realizing how a projection matrix works was a fun insight. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29

Comment: There is also a `THREE.OrthographicCamera` class available and three.js comes with an [example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_camera_orthographic.html) on it.